# Passing file path to app after double click on file

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to open a file with my own Windows Forms C# program after making it a default app for certain file extensions.

From Stack Overflow and other websites I found out that in such situations windows passing file paths as command-line arguments, so theoretically file path should be in args[0], but I can't find it there.

In the case of pulling the file icon to app.exe everything is fine and the file path could be found in the argument list. Also, there was a proposition of creating a registry record with app path and "%1" in a specific registry folder. I've checked my registry and the record is there.

Maybe I'm missing something simple? Most answers in similar topics are saying about args[0]. But unfortunately, this isn`t my case.

Example code from *main.cs*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       if (args.Length != 0 && File.Exists(args[0]))
       {
         fileName = args[0];
         doSmth(filename);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Can you please update your post to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Currently we don't know what you've tried and what isn't working, for us to help please provide in detail what you've tried.

Comment: After running your app with double click on the file of the associated filetype, check the windows task manager for a command line of your app (details tab + you may need to show corresponding column manually). Do you see a path to the selected file in the command line arguments here?

Comment: @Serg nope, they aren`t there

Comment: If there is no path in task manager, then the problem not in your C# code, but in the filetype registration. I do not know how to further diagnose this except the comparing the registry with other (working) filetype.

Comment: @serg thanks once again for yours answer. It helped a lot. It turned out that during the testing of app assingment i passed to my ftype parametr the app link without "%1"

Answer (score 0):

Value of ***ftype*** caused this problem. Before using "open with" i was using *assoc* and *ftype* to manually set my app as default. It turned out that in order to pass file path properly to your app you need to have a "%1" at the end of your link. 
**If you manually made custom ftype variables they will override registry links**

Yours ftype variable should look in such way:

```
ftype custom_var=link_to_app %1
```